# Include Java JAR file in Kohana

Tags: java, php, jar, cron, kohana

I'm running a cron within the Kohana framework, executing the line

```
php index.php --uri=nameofcron
```

where nameofcron is the name of my controller which drives the cron. 
During this cron's execution, I need to run an exec() statement which executes a java jar executable file.  The jar file needs to access resources within a src folder which resides at the same directory level as the jar file. When running this exec() statement within a simple php script in said directory, the exec() runs fine.  However when trying to run the exec() statement within my cron's Kohana execution path, it gives me an error saying that resources within the src folder are not found.

Is there a way to include java resources within the Kohana framework so that I can use them within a cron execution?

Comment: First change the working directory, then execute the jar command in that changed directory. You can put the cd command in front of the java command: `cd /home/path/to; java the.jar` - that's UNIX, you haven't written which platform you use.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to change the working directory before running the command (as @hakre said), or you need to include the src folder and the jar itself on the classpath.

If you want to change the cwd without using the `cd` command, I suggest using [`proc_open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

To find the path to the jar file programatically I suggest you use [`Kohana::find_file(...)`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Kohana#find_file).